# Disable Highlighted Variable in android studio

Tags: android

In Android studio,the variable longitude is Highlighted in Green by Cntrl+shift+f7
How to disable this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does'nt that put you in search mode? try pressing x on top of UI to exit search mode, if its not that then its probably a bug